# Just change the name of the app executable for an iPhone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I have an iPhone app where I will be using it as a template for several apps. I want to change the name of the executable for each individual app (Not the app display name on the phone).

I see in the target build settings where I can change the key "Product Name" to the new executable name I want.

Is there anything else I need to change?

It seems to compile, just want to make sure I don't get any problems when signing the distribution build or anything else.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Snow Leopard, Xcode now provides a "Project > Rename…" menu item that will rename all aspects of a project, including the executable name.

Answer (score 6):

For xcode 4: [Your target] -> [Build settings] -> [Product name]

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read this, which is vaguely related to what you’re asking:

http://arustisha.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/on-the-renaming-of-xcode-projects/

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Xcode 4: If you have set your product name in the info.plist file you should change it there. You will obviously need to generate a new code signing certificate for all of your build targets that you want to run on the phone itself.

Comment: Thanks. Edited to reflect that.