# How can i change executable name?

Tags: iphone, xcode

On uploading to the appstore, i'm getting

> This bundle is invalid. The executable
>   name, as reported by
>   CFBundleExecutable in the Info.plust
>   file, may not contain any of these
>   characters \ [ ] { } ( ) . + *

My app contains a +. How can i change this?

Comment: This post should answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17158773/2123093

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open the Info.plist file of your project and put an other name in the value for the CFBundleExecutable. It's probably something like ${EXECUTABLE_NAME} right now and you can put anything there. It's not visible to the end user of your app.

Comment: Changing this gives me an error of `Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)`

Comment: @Andrew, you have to update the Info.plist and perform another archive.  That will code-sign your new bundle.

Comment: Changing `CFBundleExecutable` has no visible effect on the executable name in Xcode 14.3.1 and simply results in asset validation failure: "No .app bundles found in the package", which is ridiculous after you've inspected the package and confirmed the existence of a bundle.

Answer (score 1):

> Since Snow Leopard, Xcode now provides a "Project > Rename…" menu item that will rename all aspects of a project, including the executable name.[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962607/just-change-the-name-of-the-app-executable-for-an-iphone-app)

Answer (score 1):

set the Bundle Display Name to ${PRODUCT_NAME} and create
an InfoPlist.strings file if you don't already have one. Then set
*that* CFBundleDisplayName to the name you want.

"CFBundleDisplayName" = "Whatever";

Then you can make your app with a + sign in the name