# Not able to submit my app to app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

[image]

While submit my app I got an error message. Anyone please suggest some solution for this.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about app store submissions and not about programming.

Comment: Actually error message is pretty clear. Have you checked Info.plist file?

Comment: yes.my app name and bundle display name are same only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5771556/how-can-i-change-executable-name maybe could be helpfull

Comment: You may want to add the contents of your info.plist to your question.

Comment: i have updated my post.but when i add some other name with executable file with +sign.i cant able to do validation.please help me out

Answer (score 1):

You have your "Bundle Display Name" set to "Noteapp (SS)"

As the error states you may not use "(" or ")"

Comment: so i have to change my Bundle Display Name to "Noteapp (SS)" right??

Comment: But my error is mention with "Executable file" what to change in that??

Answer (score 0):

Check your Bundle identifier. It is `com.sathishchinniah.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)`

The bundle identifier should not contain "$,(,),:" or other special characters while submitting to appstore.

Set the Bundle identifier to `com.sathishchinniah.yourappname`.

Also make sure u follow the above rule in build Name.