# Xcode: "A sealed resoeurce is missing or invalid" -- main executable is not being codesigned

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

When deploying an app to Appstore Connect using Xcode 14.3.1 I get the message that "a sealed resource is missing or invalid" and it points out that *the main executable file* in my app is "not properly signed".

This is a file whose name Xcode generated automatically with its own default settings, and which it has offered to sign automatically...

This has worked fine before -- with the identical non-ASCII characters file name -- but no more.

[Changing `CFBundleExecutable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771691/220820) from `$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)` into a hardcoded ASCII-only value in info.plist has no visible effect on the executable name. Instead, that simply results in a broken package with an asset validation failure: "No .app bundles found in the package". That's ridiculous, since I've inspected the package and confirmed the existence of the bundle.

Not that it's clear what `CFBundleExecutable` is supposed to be; a reference, or a source of truth? The brilliant definition in the docs simply reads "[For an app, this key is the executable.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleexecutable)" Right...

Answer (score -1):

The only solution to Xcode's new-found inability to handle alphabetical characters outside of ASCII seems to be to **define `EXECUTABLE_NAME` as a custom build option** and set it to something easily digestible. I did not dare use whitespace or even uppercase, and settled on lowercase and hyphen. It seems to have done the trick.

I thought these kinds of problems had been solved with the transition away from HFS...